# Слушатель для кнопок из layout-land активити (Andriod)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

Делаю калькулятор под Android. В портретной ориентации базовый набор кнопок, в альбомной есть несколько дополнительных. Проблема в том, что не могу подключить слушатель для этих дополнительных кнопок.

OnClickListener имплементирую в MainActivity. Нажатие всех кнопок обрабатываю в одном onClick методе. Когда пытаюсь назначить слушатель для этих дополнительных кнопок, приложение падает.

Использую такой же код, как и для остальных кнопок:

```
btn_other.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Может для элементов landscape активити нужно как то по другому назначать слушатель?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это происходит из за того, что в одной из ориентаций нет виджетов, ссылки на которые вы хотите получить и вместо объекта кнопки возвращается `null`.

Решить можно двумя способами:

Если это активити (не фрагмент), то вы можете указать слушатель нажатия непосредственно в разметке самой кнопки (кнопок). Слушатель может быть один на несколько кнопок, каждая из которых затем определяется по ID переданного `View`:

```
<Button ...
    android:id="+@id/landButton
    android:onClick = "onClick"/>
```

теперь при нажатии на кнопку, будет вызван метод `onClick()` - этот метод должен иметь определенную сигнатуру:

```
public void onClick(View view){
  switch (view.getId()){
   case R.id.landButton: //нажали на кнопку landButtin;
        break;
   }
}
```

имя метода может быть любым разрешенным в Java. У способа такой недостаток, что так можно только назначить слушатель, если в коде требуются другие обращения к кнопке (например, изменить название), то он не подходит, так как в одной из ориентаций ссылка на кнопку не будет получена.

Другой вариант - просто перед каждым использованием кнопки, которая присутствует только на одной из ориентаций проверять ее на `null`:

```
Button landButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.landButton);
if (landButton != null) {
    // действия с кнопкой
}
```

Comment: Действительно, назначить слушатель через разметку не догадался. И как оказалось, в моей ситуации это наиболее удобный вариант ).

Answer (score 1):

> Может для элементов landscape активити нужно как то по другому назначать слушатель?

Нет - это бред.

> Нажатие всех кнопок обрабатываю в одном onClick методе.

Это не очень хороший паттерн - вешайте на каждую кнопку свой слушатель.

Советую поставить [ButterKnife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/), тогда код значительно упростится. Бонусом вы получите возможность просто и быстро назначать слушатели на любые кнопочки, типа:

```
@OnClick(R.id.myButton)
public void onClickMyButton(View view) {
  //blah-blah
}
```

С помощью аннотации `@Optional` можно назначить слушателя только в том случае, когда R.id.myButton != null

```
@Optional
@OnClick(R.id.myButton)
public void onClickMyButton(View view) {
  //blah-blah
}
```

Comment: Почему не хорошо использовать один onClick метод? А если я хочу добавить Haptic Feedback или что-то подобное? Неудобно ведь для каждой кнопки по отдельности прописывать, особенно если их 20-30 штук.

Comment: @kulikovman, у способа через разметку очень много ограничений и если вы на одно из них наткнётесь, то ошибка в логах почти не позволит вам понять что именно произошло и кто виноват. Как пример - во фрагментах такой способ вовсе не работает.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб какие еще ограничения, кроме фрагментов?

Comment: @pavlofff, если не ошибаюсь, то можно опечататься в разметке в имени метода и оно скомпилится и будет в раньше падать. Что в итоге сложно отловить будет

Comment: @ЮрийСПб В Android Studio автоподстановка метода с совпадающей сигнатурой кликера. Только нужно сначала написать метод для обработки кликов и потом он будет доступен в выпадающем списке параметра `android:onClick` в графическом режиме. В любом случае отловить, что клик не выполняется задача не из сложных. Сама по себе реализация просто неявно реализует тот же самый интерфейс `OnClickListener` при инфлейте разметки.

Comment: @pavlofff, я понимаю, что если знать как оно работает то можно им пользоваться) Просто я помню сколько было тут вопросов связанных с этим методом от новичков которые натыкались на все возможные грабли, включая фрагменты и опечатки. Засим и опасен этот метод - новичку сложно понять что не так